# Install VLC plugin on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vlc, plugins, media

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with VLC media player installed and I have also installed mozilla-plugin-vlc. I can see that vlc web plugin is installed at mozilla (about:addons)but not at chrome(chrome://plugins/).

Do you know how I can install that?

I couldn't find anything helpful in the net.

Comment: Are you running Chromium (not Chrome)? Newer versions of Chromium have dropped support for NPAPI plugins (like the VLC plugin).

Comment: @hal7df thanks a lot for your comment. No, I am running Chrome... Do you have any clue what might be the problem and how I can install that? Actually I do not care if I install vlc, I just want to install something at chrome, in order to play asx music files...

Comment: Type `chrome:version` into the URL bar. Does the `Chrome` line have the word `aura` in it?

Comment: @hal7df No, it doesn't have this word. Btw my version is '35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914)'

Comment: Okay. On the plugins page, click 'details'. Do any of the plugins show up as NPAPI? If not, then you probably have a version of Chrome that doesn't support it.

Comment: @hal7df No. Every single plugin has type PPAPI instead..

Comment: Sorry...doesn't look like you'll be able to use the VLC plugin (I didn't know they had taken support out of mainstream Chrome already...). Unfortunately, I don't believe that there is an alternative to your situation other than to download the stream for and open it in VLC. I'm kind of surprised that Google made this step before PPAPI became established...

Comment: See this forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225277

Comment: Hmmm... Therefore, the forums says that I cannot install the plugin? @hal7df

Comment: No, you can't. I can't think of any way to solve your problem other than to use a different browser.

Comment: well this is.... ridiculous :(

Answer (score 5):

As I know, Chrome uses PPAPI-based plugins ONLY now, while vlc-browser-plugin is NPAPI-based, so it's unavailable for Chrome. Just use another browser.